# What role does this diode play in this reverse voltage protector circuit?

Tags: reverse-polarity

I have been trying to understand this schematic, which is I believe intended to be provide reverse voltage protection.  I understand most of the aspects of this.  The basic idea is that D3 allows current to flow in the proper direction, which then will turn the mosfet M1 on.  The mosfet will then provide a lower-resistance path for the majority of the current in the system to flow through.  The zener diode D2 and resistor are there to allow for a wider range of input voltages while keeping within the mosfet's gate-source voltage tolerance.

What I don't understand is why D1 would be in the circuit at all.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frSmlF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A few notes about this schematic. The 24V voltage source is intended to be input from an external voltage source, and VCC and GND labels are the effective voltage source for the rest of the board.

I found this schematic in the open source Smoothieboard's design, which can be found here for further reference https://github.com/Smoothieware/Smoothieboard.

Answer (score 2):

D1 looks like an inductive back emf protection diode. When the current is cutoff from an inductive load the magnetic field collapses causing a large negative voltage spike that D1 conducts to ground.

Answer (score 0):

The diode D1 serves as a flyback diode during the turn off of the mosfet,
the current flow in a p channel mosfet would be from source to drain.

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't understand is why D1 would be in the circuit at all.

To protect the load from reverse polarity. The max reverse voltage the load will see is 0.7v due to the diode.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's likely that D1 in your schematic is not a part of this particular "module". Just because it appears close the the MOSFET in the Smoothie schematic does not necessarily mean it forms part of the "MOSFET's periphery".

The MOSFET may provide protection from negative voltages applied on the left (to its own drain), but it cannot protect anything from violations on the other side.

It seems more likely to me that this diode is general protection against negative voltages imposed upon Vcc from *other* circuitry on the right side, connected to Vcc.